# How to display quick part > document property in word using macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field

I have two custom column in quick part mapped from sharepoint edit template.
DocSigner and DSigneromment

[image]

Now i have write macro code in word for get all builtinproperties and custom properties. I am able to get all built in document properties like Author ,Title and all but not able to get that custom column using "CustomDocumentProperties"..

Here is my macro code..

```
Sub ListAllProperties()

 Dim rngDoc As Range
 Dim proDoc As DocumentProperty

 Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.Content

 rngDoc.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

 For Each proDoc In ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties 

 With rngDoc
   .InsertParagraphAfter
   .InsertAfter proDoc.Name & "= "
   On Error Resume Next
   .InsertAfter proDoc.Value
 End With

 Next

End Sub
```

So any code changes that i can get all document property from quick part.

Comment: HOW is the code you show us not working? And take `On Error Resume Next` out - that's not something to just stick in because you're seeing an error. You need to know the error and fix it, not simply suppress it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bibadia Thanks a lot for your contribution

Here is finally i have tried for custom property and it works...

```
Sub ListContentTypeProperty()

Dim signer As String

signer = ActiveDocument.ContentTypeProperties.Item("DocSigner")

MsgBox signer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of properties coming from custom SharePoint columns, use the Document's ContentTypeProperties collection.